# minimal example of Python's bottle microframework using gevent-socketio and Socket.IO.js

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, gevent, bottle

**Question:**  What would be a comparable solution to the example at [this link](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html#finally-websockets), except implemented using [gevent-socketio](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent-socketio/) and [Socket.io.js](http://socket.io/) with [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/)?  I'm looking for the minimal solution that will simply pass some traffic in a loop from the client to the server and back to the client using gevent-socketio, Socket.io.js, and bottle.

**Background:** I have developed a simple web-app that provides a web-based terminal for a remote custom shell (cli) on the server.  The browser (client) collects shell commands from a form input field, passes the command over a web-socket to a `gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer` handling the requests via the `geventwebsocket.WebSocketHandler` handler, which supplies the command to the shell, while asynchronously returning output via the socket to a textarea field in a form in the client's browser.  This is based on a great, little example provided by the bottle team:

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html#finally-websockets

Provided here for redundancy:

**example_server.py**:

```
from bottle import request, Bottle, abort
app = Bottle()

@app.route('/websocket')
def handle_websocket():
    wsock = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
    if not wsock:
        abort(400, 'Expected WebSocket request.')

    while True:
        try:
            message = wsock.receive()
            wsock.send("Your message was: %r" % message)
        except WebSocketError:
            break

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket import WebSocketHandler, WebSocketError
server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 8080), app,
                    handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

**client.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.com:8080/websocket");
    ws.onopen = function() {
        ws.send("Hello, world");
    };
    ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
        alert(evt.data);
    };
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

**Motivation:**  My existing app works great in the latest version of Firefox and Chrome.  IE support is non-existent, and Safari compatibility is middlin'.  I'm ultimately looking for a cross-browswer solution to communicate shell commands and output between the client and server.  If I had a simple example for bottle, I think I could move forward more quickly.

Incidentally, I looked at the [gevent-socketio examples](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/tree/master/examples) and even [a bottle example](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/pull/245), but all of these examples are too different from the above simple example for me to make the leap in application.  (The gevent-socketio examples look nothing like the bottle apps, which which I'm familiar.  And, the bottle example doesn't actually show how to communicate with the client.)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Circus](https://github.com/mozilla-services/circus)! the process runner and watcher built on top of zmq, use bottle and socketio for the web interfaces:

https://github.com/mozilla-services/circus/blob/master/circus/web/circushttpd.py
https://github.com/mozilla-services/circus/blob/master/circus/web/server.py

The source code is simple enough for helping you to get started to build a bigger app with bottle and socketio.

Otherwise, I advice you to move to [sockjs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)! which a more generic implementation with better support for different backends.

This other thread can help you : 
[SockJS or Socket.IO? Worth to recode ajax-based page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341593/sockjs-or-socket-io-worth-to-recode-ajax-based-page)

Comment: The links provided are broken now. The files can be found here:
https://github.com/mozilla-services/circus-web/blob/c850fcf453dd53680885833f3e0944577e90385b/circusweb/circushttpd.py
https://github.com/mozilla-services/circus-web/blob/c850fcf453dd53680885833f3e0944577e90385b/circusweb/server.py